# numpy opencv flip set of rows

Tags: python, sorting, opencv, numpy

Which would be the best way to get a an image array with all odd rows flipped?

this is the input image:

```
   A[ ROW.0 = 0 , 1 , 2 , 3
      ROW.1 = 0 , 1 , 2 , 3
      ROW.2 = 0 , 1 , 2 , 3
      ROW.3 = 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 
]
```

this should be the output

```
 B[ ROW.0 = 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 
    ROW.1 = 3 , 2 , 1 , 0 
    ROW.2 = 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 
    ROW.3 = 3 , 2 , 1 , 0 
]
```

I believe this can be done with a for

```
for i in img[::2]:     # take odd rows
   b = i[::-1]         # reverse elements order
         print b
```

or there is a better method using numpy or opencv?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
In [7]: a = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]])                                                                            

In [8]: a[1::2] = a[1::2,::-1]

In [9]: a
Out[9]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],                                                                             
       [3, 2, 1, 0],                                                                             
       [0, 1, 2, 3],                                                                             
       [3, 2, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: thanks! please let me understand: a[1::2] means get every next item, starting with the second?